# Moving a lotus database causes incoming mail failure

Tags: ibm-domino

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving a lotus database causes incoming mail failure](https://serverfault.com/questions/249438/moving-a-lotus-database-causes-incoming-mail-failure)

Hey all, I moved a couple lotus note databases to another hd (ran out of space) by using a directory link/pointer on the domino server. USed a text file with the .DIR ext with the desired new path etc... well that works fine. I open up a lotus notes client, use the id and then OPEN the database. The directory link works fine, the new location of the db is opened with no problems. We found out that we couldnt FORWARD any mail: We did the following to make it work:

Goto menu FILE|MOBILE|EDIT CURRENT LOCATION Goto tab MAIL and enter the correct path for "Mail File:" example: it should read "mail\morespace\flabor" and not "mail\flabor"

"morespace" = directory link/pointer

we can forward and reply to emails fine after that fix. The problem is that the user has no incoming email. Domino is still trying to send the incoming mail of that user to its old db location "mail\flabor" instead of "mail\morespace\flabor". Delivery error saying user does not exist.

Is this a cache problem? We have reset the server ("Q" at the prompt), though we have not completely shut it down though.

Thanks Frank

Answer (score 1):

Did you bounce the mail router?

Tell Router Quit
Load Router

Also check your mail.box file(s) to see if the messages are just queued up waiting to get delivered.