# Moving a lotus database causes incoming mail failure

Tags: lotus-notes, ibm-domino

I moved a couple lotus note databases to another hd (ran out of space) by using a directory link/pointer on the domino server. USed a text file with the .DIR ext with the desired new path etc... well that works fine. I open up a lotus notes client, use the id and then OPEN the database. The directory link works fine, the new location of the db is opened with no problems. We found out that we couldnt FORWARD any mail: We did the following to make it work:

Goto menu FILE|MOBILE|EDIT CURRENT LOCATION
Goto tab MAIL and enter the correct path for "Mail File:"
example: it should read "mail\morespace\flabor" and not "mail\flabor"

"morespace" = directory link/pointer

we can forward and reply to emails fine after that fix.
The problem is that the user has no incoming email. Domino is still trying to send the incoming mail of that user to its old db location "mail\flabor" instead of "mail\morespace\flabor". Delivery error saying user does not exist.

Is this a cache problem? We have reset the server ("Q" at the prompt), though we have not completely shut it down though.

Thanks
Frank

Comment: This is a server-fault type question, but I doubt you'll get enough votes to move it, so I've answered it below :)

Comment: @Ken - if you don't think it will get enough votes you can always flag it for a moderator to "help it along".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to change the mail file location specified in the Person document of the Domino Directory.

Answer (score 1):

There is an admin procedures for moving mail accounts, which can be found [here](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_admin.nsf/b3266a3c17f9bb7085256b870069c0a9/634ced33f7abb79e85256c1d00391f5d?OpenDocument) for version 6.5/7.0 and [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/MOVING_A_MAIL_FILE.html) for version 8+.

As you're sort of half way through a move in the scheme of things you could try the following.

1. Goto the relevant person document entry in the Name and Address book (NAB) on the server.
2. Check the mail file setting on the basics tab.
3. Goto your location documents defined in your local NAB, (can be found under Advanced, then select "locations").
4. Typically the location called "online" is the default that users have. Goto the "mail" tab and check the mail file locations there to.

The SMTP router process should pick this up immediately, failing that you can restart the SMTP process, [here](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21090075). Restarting the Domino server or event the host O/S might be a bit of overkill for this sort of activity.

Comment: we had to restart the server after adjusting  the NABs. This was domino v5

Comment: R5 !?!? LOL....